# Error inserting datetime into mysql datetime column using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm trying to insert the datetime into a mysql column but I'm getting this error:

```
Error: INSERT INTO prices (priceLBTC, dt) VALUES (421.59, 2015-12-27 15:41:09) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '15:41:09)' at line 2
```

Here is the code I'm using to get the datetime and insert it into the "dt" datetime type column.

```
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$date = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$sql = "INSERT INTO prices (priceLBTC, dt)
VALUES ($bitcoinPrice, $date)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: Put quotes around `$date`. Alternatively, consider using `timestamps`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting error cause your datetime value is not quoted as seen below and so DB engine throwing an error assuming you meant to provide more values.

```
INSERT INTO prices (priceLBTC, dt) VALUES (421.59, 2015-12-27 15:41:09)
                                                   ^.. Here
```

You need to quote your datetime value using single quote like

```
INSERT INTO prices (priceLBTC, dt) VALUES (421.59, '2015-12-27 15:41:09')
```

Comment: That's it, thanks! I didn't think it needed any because the price had none originally.

Answer (score 1):

`$sql = "INSERT INTO prices (priceLBTC, dt)
VALUES (".$conn->quote($bitcoinPrice).", ".$conn->quote($date).")";`